# Rでデータフレーム内の二列を結合し新しい列を作りたい

Tags: r

Rでデータフレーム内の二列を結合し新しい列を作りたく、
https://www.trifields.jp/how-to-add-multiple-joined-columns-by-specifying-multiple-columns-as-strings-in-dplyr-package-in-r-2812
を参考に

```
data2 <- data %>% mutate(NewCol = paste(!!!rlang::syms(c("var1", "var2")), sep=" "))
```

としましたが、

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "character"
```

となってしまいます。

ちなみにvar1はyymmdd、var2はhmsをcharacterに変換したものです。
（最初のDate型やhms型でもエラーが出たため。）

また、単純に文字列結合してもよいのですが、一気に年月日時分秒を表わせる型は存在するのでしょうか。
調べると

```
strptime(datetime,"%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
```

というのが存在するようですがこれは自分でフォーマットを指定しているだけでデフォルトで用意されている型とは違うようですね…

Answer (score 1):

> 一気に年月日時分秒を表わせる型は存在するのでしょうか。

lubridateパッケージのymd_hms関数を使って2018-2-24 15:30:15のような文字列を代入すると行けそうですね。
質問してすぐに下のページを見つけてしまいました。自己回答すいません。

https://kazutan.github.io/SappoRoR8/01-lubridate.html

エラーの方は原因がよくわからないので教えていただけると幸いです。